# Are there any ready solutions for string(html) parsing with actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, parsing, apache-flex, html-parsing, flex4

I need to parse string entered to textarea for 2 reasons:

1. Remove all html tags except small number that are allowed;
2. Check if html tags are positioned correctly: `<i><b> wow </i></b>` is incorrect.

Are there any 'build-in' solutions or libraries for that deal? Using regExp is not ok for this task - it's very complex and generally bad idea to parse html structure with them.

Comment: you can use xml parsing, because html is kinda like xml

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this from AS3? If you have text from an HTML textarea wouldn't it be easier to do the scrubbing using the HTML DOM with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **[unescape](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#escape())** function. 
Usage : `clean_String = unescape( input_String );`

Or else...

You can try the **[decode URI component](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#decodeURIComponent())** function.
Usage : `clean_String = decodeURIComponent( input_String );`

In each case `clean_String` is an empty string that will be updated by the result of the functions. `input_String` is the string with the HTML entities that is to be decoded or unescaped etc.